# Simultaneous minimization with respect to two parameters

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I am struggling with the minimization of a solution of an ODE with respect to two parameters. Here is the code I write:

```
ε = 10^-6;

solw = NDSolve[{w''[t] + (w[t] + w[t]^2) w'[t] == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 t]), w[0] == 0, 
w'[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 2 π}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. solw]

solG[s2_] := 
NDSolve[{G''[t] + (G[t] + G[t]^2) G'[t] == s2 1/(Sqrt[π] ε) Exp[-(t/ε)^2], G[0] == 0, 
   G'[0] == 0}, G, {t, 0, 2 π}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"]
Gsol[t_] := Evaluate[G[t] /. solG[s2]]
approx[t_] := 
 s1 NIntegrate[Gsol[t - τ] 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 τ]), {τ, 0, t}, Method -> "DoubleExponential"]

tab = Table[Abs[wsol[t] - approx[t]], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
NMinimize[Max[tab], s1, s2]
```

However, this works only if I fix `s2` in the definition of `solG` and minimize `tab` with respect to `s1`. Any idea how can I extend the algorithm to minimize `tab` with respect to both `s1` and `s2`?

**Edit**

I have modified the code a bit using `ParametricNDSolve`. Now it looks like:

```
ε = 10^-6;

    solw = NDSolve[{w''[t] + (w[t] + w[t]^2) w'[t] == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 t]), w[0] == 0, 
    w'[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 2 π}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
    wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. solw]

    solG= 
    ParametricNDSolve[{G''[t] + (G[t] + G[t]^2) G'[t] == s2 1/(Sqrt[π] ε) Exp[-(t/ε)^2], G[0] == 0, 
       G'[0] == 0}, G, {s2}, {t, 0, 2 π}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"]
    Gsol[t_,s2_] := Evaluate[G[s2][t] /. solG]
    approx[t_,s1_,s2_] := 
     s1 NIntegrate[Gsol[τ,s2] 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 (t-τ)]), {τ, 0, t}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

Comment: What is the point of defining `approx`? `tab` does not depend on `s1` or `approx`.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer.

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-6;
Delta[t_] := 1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] \[Epsilon]) Exp[-(t/\[Epsilon])^2]
f[t_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 t])

solw = NDSolve[{w''[t] + Exp[w[t]] == f[t], w[0] == 0, w'[0] == 0}, 
   w, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. solw]

solG = ParametricNDSolve[{G''[t] + Exp[G[t]] == s2 Delta[t], 
    G[0] == 0, G'[0] == 0}, G, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {s2}, 
   Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
GGreen[t_, s2_] := Evaluate[G[s2][t] /. solG]
Gsol[t_, s1_, s2_] := 
 s1 NIntegrate[GGreen[\[Tau], s2] f[t - \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

interpol = 
  ListInterpolation[
   Table[Gsol[t, s1, s2], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}, {s2, -5, 5, 0.1}], {{0, 
     1}, {-5, 5}}];

NMinimize[{Max[
   Table[Abs[wsol[t] - interpol[t, s2]], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]], -5 <= s2 <=
    5}, {s1, s2}]
```

However, one needs to be careful with choosing the range of `s2` in the NMinimize. For `-1 <= 2 <=2` the solution is better than for `-3 <= s2 <=3`. This means that there might be a better solution.